# How can I show that this sequence is monotone and bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

How can I show that the following sequence is monotone and bounded?

$a_1=1, a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n}{2}+1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

The exercise asks to find the limit of the sequence (if it exists), and suggests to first, show that $(a_n)_n$ is monotone and bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show it is Montone and bounded by induction easily. First, check that $a_1\leq 2$ and $1=a_1 < a_2=1.5$. Now suppose that $a_n<a_{n+1}<2$ for some $n$. Then, we have $$a_n/2+1</a_{n+1}/2+1<2/2+1=2$$ which implies that $a_{n+1}<a_{n+2} <2$.

you can generally show that if $f(x)$ is a monotone function the $a_{n+1} =f(a_n)$ is a monotone sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Interpret the sequence as $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+2}{2}$, and is therefore the average of the previous term with $2$. You started below $2$, so what happens when you average against it?

Comment: I see... The result is going to be a little bit over the previous one, but always below 2. Now, how do I formalize that idea?

Comment: Well, for monotonicity, it seems easy to prove that the average of two numbers is between them. Since $2$ is a fixed quantity you're averaging against, it should be easy to establish the increasing property. For the boundedness, well, you know the bound. So maybe try to prove by induction that each term is less than $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: $1\le a_n\le 2$ for all $n$. The base case is given, and if $1\le a_n\le 2$, then $\frac12\le \frac{a_n}{2}\le 1$, so $\frac32\le\frac{a_n}{2}+1\le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is determine a candidate value for the limit. If the limit exists, then we have

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n + 1} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{2} + 1 = 1 + \frac{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n}{2}$$

Let $L = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$, if it exists. Then $L = 1 + \frac{L}{2}$, so $L = 2$.

So if the limit exists, the limit is 2.

Now, define $b_n = 2 - a_n$. We would expect to see that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$.

Then we see that $b_0 = 1$ and $b_{n + 1} = 2 - a_{n + 1} = 2 - (1 + \frac{a_n}{2}) = \frac{2 - a_n}{2} = \frac{b_n}{2}$.

Therefore, we see easily that $b_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$, and thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2 - b_n = 2 - \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = 2$.

Alternately, you can note that since $b_{n + 1} = \frac{b_n}{2}$, that $b_n$ is always positive and that $b$ is decreasing. Therefore, $a$ is increasing, and $a_n$ is always less than $2$. So $a$ must converge, and thus must converge to 2.

Comment: Yea, I did t he first step on my notebook! But this is just an assumption, correct? It doesn't prove that $L$ is the limit, right?

Comment: @msmilkshake It does not. But once we know that the limit should be 2, this allows us to figure out how to define $b$. We then do the proof using $b$, which doesn't depend on the earlier calculation. If I had just started with "define $b_n = 2 - a_n$", you would have no idea where that came from.

Comment: Makes total sense!  thanks.

Comment: I upvoted, but I believe someone downvoted, because this doesn't demonstrate how to show that the sequence is monotone and bounded, but I found your answer very educational!!

Comment: @msmilkshake Yes, I added a bit at the end about how you could go that route using the $b_n$ definition.